# Best way to enforce valid table names when writing to a File Geodatabase

Tags: error, fme-form, file-geodatabase, tab, regular-expression

I have an FME Workbench which reads MapInfo files and writes them to a File Geodatabase.  Generally, the workbench works pretty well, however, I've just come across an error which I though would have been handled by FME automatically.

One of the files has parentheses in the filename: `AsBuilt_Crossings(Start).TAB`

When FME processes this file, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while attempting to create the feature class AsBuilt_Crossings(Start)_point'. 

The error number from ArcObjects is: '-2147220654'. 

The error message from ArcObjects is: {The table name is invalid.}
```

I'm guessing that the geodatabase doesn't like having the ( and ) characters.  This is something that I would have thought FME would take care of automatically, but clearly not.  Is there a way I can remove these characters (and any other invalid characters) from the name before it writes it?

I'm thinking a [**StringReplacer**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/stringreplacer.htm) transformer with some sort of Regular Expression to replace the invalid characters with an underscore.  However, I'm not sure if I should replace the characters on `fme_basename` or `fme_dataset`.  I'm also not sure of the regular expression to use.

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: How have you set up your writer? E.g. static, fanout, dynamic?

Comment: The writer is dynamic because I want to read all TABs in a folder and write to a geodatabase.  TAB filenames should become the feature class names with "_point", "_line", or "_polygon" appended automatically as appropriate.  No fanouts.

Comment: How are you appending _point, _line or _polygon to the feature type name? Or is that the TAB reader's doing? Either way, you should be able to set the output feature type name via an attribute if you look in the dynamic schema properties). Typically you would just change the `fme_feature_type` attribute.

Comment: FME automatically appends _point, _line, _polygon or _annotation because a feature class can only support one geometry type.  Whereas, a TAB file can support multiple types in one file.  But I'm not concerned about that.  I'm wondering how to get rid of the () characters in the file name.

Comment: Furthermore, if I rename fme_feature_type, I get an error saying it can't find the schema definition because it's getting the definition from fme_feature_type.

Comment: Try creating a new attribute, replacing the invalid characters and using that as the output feature type name. I forget which setting it is and don't have FME available at the moment so couldn't tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: I thought about that, but in order to fan out by that, I lose the dynamic aspect of the workbench.  It also wants me to specify the allowed geometry which I won't know beforehand.

Comment: There are three properties on the dynamic schema properties window that you can set. Change the first one to an attribute that contains the desired output feature type name. The other two can be set independent of the first, or each other for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I think you are on the right track using the StringReplacer and as blah238 says, creating a new attribute for the new string.  If you look in the properties of the destination feature type for the dynamic writer you will see "Schema Definition. Here you can make a setting to get the feature type name from an attribute (the new one you created) rather than from the source name which is the default.

BTW
It is a known issue that we don't properly validate these names for the geodatabase writer